# Documenting Ruby code results within source file

Tags: ruby, testing, documentation

This is a really basic question. I've been watching [Ruby Tapas](http://www.rubytapas.com) and really like how Avdi can run his Ruby code and have it recorded directly in the source file. Googling "executing and documenting Ruby code" obviously returns a bunch of stuff about the RDocs for the language itself. Anyone know more specifically what I should look into?

Comment: which editor you are using ?

Comment: wait,,, giving you solutions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`t9md / vim-ruby-xmpfilter`](https://github.com/t9md/vim-ruby-xmpfilter). Look also the [`README`](https://github.com/t9md/vim-ruby-xmpfilter/blob/master/README.md) section.

You need to have [`rcodetools`](http://rubygems.org/gems/rcodetools) gem mandatory.

After that go though the [issue](https://github.com/t9md/vim-ruby-xmpfilter/issues/6#issuecomment-31298901), I logged.

Comment: Awesome! Took me a bit to get my mappings to work. Command key maps don't seem to work for me. Not sure why :-/ Thanks for the help!